# Is there a way to get the App selected language or culture when running Xamarin.UITests

Tags: testing, xamarin, cultureinfo, uitest

We am currently adding localization throughout an app that we are using and have haven't had any big problems with displaying differing UI depending on the culture.
When attempting to update the tests I haven't been able to find a way to get the culture of the app/system from within the test (for formatting money to check against selection).

I've tried using `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture`, `Thread.CurrentCulture` and the more verbose forms of Thread culture info (both default and UIThread).

Does anyone know of how to do this or if it is even possible?

Answer (score 0):

```
var culture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
```

called from within a test works just fine.